# Using transitionToRoute, passing a route without a dynamic segment the current model causes error

Tags: ember.js

I have a route defined in the Router as:

```
...
this.resource('cart', {path: 'my/cart'});
...

MyApp.CartRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return this.store.find('cart');
    }
});
```

In my CartController (ArrayController) I have this line of code in an action (addToCart):

```
this.transitionToRoute('cart', this.get('model'));
```

In some other route's template, I call that action:

```
<button {{action 'addToCart' product target='controllers.cart'}}>Add To Cart</button>
```

When that button is clicked, I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: More context objects were passed than there are dynamic segments for the route: cart
```

To my understanding, Ember should have recognized that I was passing it a model and skipped the model hook, which is what I want.

This can be fixed by adding a random, useless dynamic segment to my route definition then defining serialize in my CartRoute. However, if there is a better way, I would rather do that.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

In

```
this.transitionToRoute('cart', this.get('model'));
```

you're sending some data object to the route `cart` which doesn't have a dynamic segment. The error message should disappear with the line

```
this.transitionToRoute('cart');
```

That said, I've got a feeling that the architecture of your application might be improvable. But I'd need more code to be sure. Anyway, you should have a look if putting the action handler somewhere else and using bubbling actions without the target could be an option. Again, that's just a feeling, I don't know enough of your code to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The reason I want to pass the model as a parameter is because I don't want it to hit the model hook and do a GET /carts each time it transitions.

Would the best thing to do in this situation be to add a check in the model hook for this.controllerFor('cart').get('model') and see if there is already a model present and return that instead of return the this.store.find('cart')?

Comment: In response to your suggestion to use bubbling actions: Is there a benefit to having Ember bubble my action vs telling Ember where my target action is? To me, it seems that the code is much easier to read and manage using target because you know exactly where that action is being called. That action is also used in many parts of the application where a product objects are.

Comment: If you just want the cached data from the store, have a look at `all` instead of `find`.

Comment: I need it to `store.find` the first time it goes to the route. Then when it returns to the route, a `store.all` is okay but I would prefer for it to just get the MutableArray that is already the CartController's model (from the first time it entered the router).

Comment: I find bubbling actions easier to grok. A target could be anywhere, so I have to start to think about structure. Bubbling is always upwards in the route tree structure.

Comment: Then (and I don't really recommend this, but don't know enough about the structure oft your app) keep a boolean, if the model hook has Bern executed before and do a `find` only if not. But maybe you should put the cart in a route that is a parent of all routes that need the cart ...

Comment: My application is quite large and complex but many of the routes that utilize the cart serve many more other purposes that are not related to the cart. From your last comment, (although you don't recommend it and because I don't see any other way) I think storing a boolean in the route and using `this.modelFor(this.routeName)` or `this.modelFor('cart')` is my best course of action. Really appreciate the information you provided. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the game here, but it sounds like you may want to have your cart be (/be managed by) a service, rather than being fetched as a model for a bunch of different specific routes. In fact, a shopping cart is the specific example currently used on the Ember docs page explaining the use of Services: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/services/#toc_defining-services

This would allow you to manage the fetching and local caching of the cart at the service level. You'd then either inject that service directly into the relevant controllers, or inject the service into the route, and have the route return the service-managed cart object as it's model.